# Force transactions in psql

Tags: psql

When I use the psql console, is it possible to force any inserts/updates/deletes to be run in a transaction? Or do I always have to explicitly start every command with 'BEGIN'?

Answer (score 0):

Appears there is an AUTOCOMMIT feature I wasn't aware of:

```
AUTOCOMMIT
When on (the default), each SQL command is automatically committed upon 
successful completion. To postpone commit in this mode, you must enter a 
BEGIN or START TRANSACTION SQL command. When off or unset, SQL commands are 
not committed until you explicitly issue COMMIT or END. The autocommit-off 
mode works by issuing an implicit BEGIN for you, just before any command 
that is not already in a transaction block and is not itself a BEGIN or 
other transaction-control command, nor a command that cannot be executed 
inside a transaction block (such as VACUUM).

Note: The autocommit-on mode is PostgreSQL's traditional behavior, but 
autocommit-off is closer to the SQL spec. If you prefer autocommit-off, you 
might wish to set it in the system-wide psqlrc file or your ~/.psqlrc file
```

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ecpg-sql-set-autocommit.html